# How to avoid two linearLayout overlapping each other in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I tried to set four buttons at the bottom of the screen and make an imageView fill the rest place. However, I tried "0dp" + "weight=1" method and several other ways suggested online (can't remember the ways I have tried exactly now), but the imageView still fills the whole screen with buttons on it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/viewImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/runtime"
        android:text="Rendering......"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btnsLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSelectPhoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="Select Photo"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSavePhoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="Save Photo"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLocalFilter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="Local Filter"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCloudFilter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="Cloud Filter"/>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Its because the first `LinearLayout` has `layout_height` set as `match_parent` and since the root is a `RelativeLayout` the second linear layout is drawn on top of the first and also since you specified `alignParentBottom` as true for the second one the buttons are drawn on top

Answer (score 3):

Set `android:layout_above="@+id/btnsLayout"` in the first `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnsLayout">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be following;

```
<RelativeLayout
 .... >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnsLayout"
        ... >
        ...button elements
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        ...
        android:layout_above="@id/btnsLayout"
        ...>
        ...image view etc
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This way you tell outmost RelativeLayout to layout LinearLayout containing ImageView above buttons containing LinearLayout.